# Что значит «он сидел на карле»?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

«Он сидел на резном черного дерева **карле**, протянув ноги к камину, у которого грелись две собаки» — что значит выделенное слово и какова его этимология?

Comment: Все, что удалось найти: в каталогах мебели есть стул "Карла" и стул "Карло".

Comment: Увы, речь не об этом: начальная форма обсуждаемого слова — карл**о**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

karło
    n III, Ms. \karłorle; lm D. \karłoreł
    szt. «fotel o esowato wygiętych nogach krzyżujących się pod siedziskiem, znany w starożytnym Egipcie i Rzymie, rozpowszechniony w średniowiecznych Włoszech»

И в переводе это значит: "кресло с изогнутыми в виде буквы s ножками, скрещёнными под сиденьем, известное в древнем Египте и Риме, распространённое в средневековой Италии". Похоже, что речь и идёт о так называемом "кресле Данте", или дантеске. Но переводчик похоже просто взял польское слово. Откуда в "Ведьмаке" Данте-то взяться? Неоткуда!

Answer (score 5):

Вы имеете в виду карла (карло) -карлик?

Как утверждает Фасмер,
ка́рла, ка́рло м., ка́рлик, укр. карла́, это возможное заимствование через польский ( karlę, karzeɫ, чеш. karel, karlík) из немецкого (д.-в.-н. karal, ср.-нем. karl), диал. "малыш", нов.-в.-н. Kerl-"молодой парень".

Согласно Соболевскому (РФВ 70, 79), др.-русск. Карло как имя собств. представлено в памятниках с середины ХV в. (дьяки Карло и Гридка Карловъ), что, по его мнению, говорит против польск. посредничества.

Собств. имя может быть связано с др.-русск. собств. Карлы (Пов. врем. лет. под 911 г.) и его, возможно, следует отделять от нарицательного.

А стул "карла", скорее всего, дизайнерский  стул Карлы Толомео, её называли королевой стульев:

https://projectfromitaly.blogspot.com/2016/12/carla-tolomeo.html

Правда, есть ещё один дизайнер - Карло Коломбо, у него тоже есть стулья, но не резные, у него техника минимализма.

Answer (score 4):

Не могу найти никакой информации, но по памяти "карло" - это стул с ручками или подлокотниками, полукресло особой формы. Вот именно такой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем глубоком детстве так назывался дедушкин стул. Этимологию вывести затрудняюсь. 
Более того, в сети находятся предметы мебели с этим именем, в моем понимании "карлами" не являющиеся, обычные стулья всего более. Но тут уже возможно переосмысление.

Comment: Спасибо! Вообще говоря, интересный случай — слово-призрак.

Answer (score 2):

Мне думается, что **карло** (в этом контексте) — это **кресло**, которое сделано из **натурального** дерева.

1. В дальнейшем повествовании книги есть такая фраза:
   *Острит, занявший **карло короля**, глядел на ведьмака исподлобья, поглаживая резные подлокотники.*
2. Нашлись варианты перевода этой книги.
   2.1. *Он сидел в невысоком резном **кресле** черного дерева, ноги вытянул в сторону очага, у которого грелись две собаки.*
   2.2. *Король сидел в резном **кресле** из черного дерева, ноги вытянул к камину, у которого грелись два пса.*
   [Мечом по голове или "Ведьмак" в версии Неизвестного Переводчика](http://www.sapkowski.su/modules.php?name=Articles&pa=showarticle&artid=114)
3. Карл (карло) — так часто характеризуют то, что сделано из цельного (не наборного, не шпонированного!) дерева:
   стул твердый КАРЛ (материал изделия: дерево бук, лак);
   детский стул Гуандун Фошань фу Карл (мебель, древесина + кожа, ручная работа);
   стул деревянный Карло (светлый орех, мягкие спинка и сиденье)…